# difficulty with firebase database. Invalid database path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[struct db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uInXE.png)  Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: https://eleicoes-f6d73.firebaseio.com/. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
 at br.com.eleicoes.eleicoes.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:37)
06-28 20:16:09.973 28933-28933/br.com.eleicoes.eleicoes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView resposta;
Button bt1;
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("https://eleicoes-f6d73.firebaseio.com/");

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]
}

// [START on_start_check_user]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    resposta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resposta);
    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String post = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            resposta.setText(post);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


// [END on_start_check_user]

private void signInAnonymously() {

    // [START signin_anonymously]
    mAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                }
            });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owmfV.png)

Comment: can you post your database structure ?, your error is at your url https://eleicoes-f6d73.firebaseio.com  , with your database structure we can help you out better to get your value

Comment: look error log pic db struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan suggest, thats right, you are referencing to the main tree node of your database, but in your  `ref.addValueEventListener` you are trying to get the post from no child

if you want to get for example the first one you can do this

first fix your reference as you say

from

```
 DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://eleicoesf6d73.firebaseio.com/");
```

to

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
```

and then in your ref just call which child you want to get the value, for example the value "1" from lula

```
ref.child("lula").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String post = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            resposta.setText(post);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

you can change from `ref.child("lula")...` to `ref.child("lula2")...`  if you want to get lula2 value

EDIT:

Since lula is not a string in your database, just change to this

```
 ref.child("lula").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

                resposta.setText(String.valueOf(post));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Perfect! I made this code! the textview does not take the value of "lula"

Comment: 06-28 22:39:52.353 5563-5599/br.com.eleicoes.eleicoes W/SyncTree: Listen at /lula failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: thats because lula is not a string in your db, i will edit my answer

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
it was false!

Comment: in firebase, a string will have " "  after you key name , for example if lula were a string it should say lula: " 1 "  , but instead it says lula: 1 and thats could be a an integer , long or double

Comment: edit:
resposta.setText(" " + post);
 is ok... what´s problem?

Comment: it works.  resposta.setText(" " + post); ok!, resposta.setText(post); crash! What?

Comment: I need now to change the value of this integer in the database

Comment: you can wrap it with resposta.setText(String.valueOf(post));

Comment: Nice! sorry!
I'm starting to learn! I need now to change the value of this integer in the database

Comment: you can change it from firebase directly by pressing the 1 value of lula, or do it programatically

Comment: to change it programatically just use ref.child("lula").setValue("30"); for example

Comment: public void bt2 (View v){
        ref.child("lula").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                post++;
                lula.setValue(Integer.valueOf(post));
                resposta.setText(" " + post);                
               
                onStop();
                return;
                           }
          ; Whats int post infinite loop post++?

Comment: if you do lula.setValue(Integer.valueOf(post)); you are posting to firebase the same value that you are retrieving in  int post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class); , so the value is constantly changing and puting inside firebase thats why you get infinite , i will suggest to you to read the official documentation of firebase to have a better knowlage of how to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't put in the node of database https://eleicoes-f6d73.firebaseio.com/
that's the error.

Comment: thats true, but the fact we dont know the database structure , we cant help to make the code works

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
  DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://eleicoesf6d73.firebaseio.com/");
```

to

```
  DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
```